# Rhyme or reason to history buffer in Windows command interpreter?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-xp, command-prompt

When I am in a shell like bash, if I use the up arrow to go through the command-line-history buffer, it behaves in a predictable way: hitting up goes to the command I executed most recently.

In the Windows cmd.exe ("DOS") shell, sometimes hitting the up arrow goes to the most recent command, sometimes it goes to the 2nd most recent command or even the 3rd most recent command.  Sometimes, to get to the most recent command I entered, I actually have to hit the *down* arrow!  Sometimes I have to hit the down arrow *twice*!

What is the logic to this?  It's been driving me batty for a long time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command selected by up/down-arrow is relative to the last-selected repeat.

So if you have executed

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

Then pressing up-arrow 3 times and `enter` would reselect and execute `line 2`

From there, you can down-arrow once to re-select `line 3` or twice for `line 4` or up-arrow once for `line 2`, twice for `line 1`

BUT the new lines executed are appended to the list and if you enter a line manually, the selector moves to the bottom of the list again.

The line will not be entered into the list if it is a duplicate of the last entry, so you can up-arrow-and-execute a thousand times if you want to and up-arrow-twice will get the (-1001st) command entered.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that by moving up through the history, I am setting a cursor of sorts within the history, and that if I enter new commands, they do get added on to the end of the history, but my "cursor" does not necessarily jump down to the newest command (as it would in bash).

Comment: If you like. a dommand is added to the bottom of the list as it is executed UNLESS it's a repeat of the previous command, but the cursor remains in-place so up-arrow selects the same command agin, down-arrow the next in the list. That way, you can repeat a sequence of commands by up-arrowing to the first and down-arrowing just once to the next. If you use up/down-arrow to change the sequence, the cursor remains at its new position in the history and the end-of-list records the altered sequence. Manually entering a new command adds it to the end AND moves the cursor to the end.